# PHP count if data is not empty

Tags: php, mysql

i need a little help here.

I am trying to count the some column but my query counting not correctly.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS zero_count FROM messages WHERE uid_fk = '$uid' AND uploads IS NOT NULL AND uploads <>'' AND option = '1'
```

Count the upload value if upload value is not empty and also check the option='1'

so if upload value is not empty and option=1 then count it.

for example:

```
uid_fk        uploads          option

  1             75,              0      Not counting because secret_option is 0  
  1            76,77,            1      Count because it is 1 and upload value is not empty
  1                              1      Not count because upload value is empty
  1             78,              1      Count because it is 1 and upload value is not empty
  1                              1      Not count because upload value is empty
  1            79,80,            0      Not count because option is 0
```

My query is counting all option=1 only but it need to count:

If upload value is not empty and option is 1 then count it.

What i need to do in query to count upload not empty and option=1 anyone can help me in this regard ?

Comment: Are you counting rows or adding the values in the uploads column ?

Comment: @robert I am trying to counting if upload value is not empty and option=1 .

Comment: What do you need SUM or COUNT ?

Comment: @AlexanderMadyuskin i need COUNT

Comment: Hmm.. shouldn't `$uid` be inside double quotes instead of single quotes? like this - `"$uid"`. Just guessing

Comment: Maybe you need to trim field uploads ?

Comment: @AlexanderMadyuskin thanks for your best think but i still try trim field uploads but all is same.

Comment: @innovation Where we are with your question ? have you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query would probably work fine, just make sure you are getting correct value in `$uid`

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM `messages` 
WHERE TRIM(IFNULL(`uploads`, '')) != '' AND `option` = '1' AND `uid_fk` = '$uid'
```

Comment: please [CLICK](https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/11222012_131358750530626_7858393301678559190_n.jpg?oh=0039d590fa22fb042945aacb0249a351&oe=562D1871) this link for screenshot.

Comment: and what you are getting ?

Comment: Okay, try running the same query in phpmyadmin with `uid_fk=13`, and see what extra record you are getting

Comment: all is same i am getting 11

Comment: No, what I am trying to say is SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE TRIM(IFNULL(`uploads`, '')) != '' AND `option` = '1' AND `uid_fk` = '13' - run this query, and see what 1 extra result coming

Comment: @kalam-pal i am trying this think dear. No extra result it is same result=11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82128/discussion-between-kamal-pal-and-innovation).

Answer (score 0):

Your need quotes around `option` its a reserved word.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'zero_count'
FROM `messages` m
WHERE `option` <> 0
  AND (`uploads` IS NOT NULL AND `uploads` <> '')
  AND uid_fk = $uid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is same result, in the question you can see the uid_fk=1 posted 6 post but some post without upload (empty). So your answer give me the same result it is showing 4 but i need 2 .

Comment: using your example data above I get 2. and if $uid is an integer it does not need quotes.